# C# web application to be transformed with Mono for Android

Tags: android, c#-4.0, xamarin.android

I have a c# web application and i want to build an android app using Mono for Android.

Is there any automatic way to use the existing code of my web application or i have to program everything from scratch using the Mono and the android application logic?

Thank

Stav

Answer (score 0):

Hard question to answer, because it is very vague. However you should be able to take most of your Business Logic and drop it into Mono for Android without much hassle. Not really knowing how your Web App is structured it is hard to say how much of it you can reuse.

But I've made an App at work, which started as a Silverlight Web App, where practically all the model code could be reused, with one minor correction, which was to use `HttpWebRequest` instead of `HttpClient` and some minor corrections to the code to make the UI update correctly and make the updates run on the UI Thread.

The way I took to get the model code into my App, was to link all the necessary files into my project, and they mostly worked. Is there an automagic way to do this? I haven't seen one as of yet. There are some extensions to Visual Studio which can help you with linking files into your project such as [Project Linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921108%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).